# How to persist intermittent text on `react-select`?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I use below code which is to render a multi selection `react-select` component. But what I found is that when I type any characters and leave the focus before select any items, the characters are not persisted.

```
import React from 'react';

import Select from 'react-select';
import makeAnimated from 'react-select/animated';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

const animatedComponents = makeAnimated();

export default function AnimatedMulti() {
  return (
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={false}
      components={animatedComponents}
      defaultValue={[colourOptions[4], colourOptions[5]]}
      isMulti
      options={colourOptions}
    />
  );
}
```

As an example of that, see below screenshot. I typed f and move the focus on other component. Then the f will be removed from the select component. Is there a way to persist the f when it loses focus?

[image]

Comment: I don't see how you can do it without converting your select to a controlled component and then control on blur method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining `inputValue`, `value`, `onInputChange` and `onChange` props.

Something like this

```
<Select
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={value => this.setState({ value })}
  inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
  onInputChange={inputValue => this.setState({ inputValue })}
/>
```

You can read more about this in the [docs](https://react-select.com/props#select-props)